# Ag-grid: Infinite Scrolling not working

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I was following the toturial and sources published on this page: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-virtual-paging/index.php

In my component I have the related code:

```
class PortsGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        console.log("PortsGrid - constructor");
        super(props);

        this.gridOptions = {
            rowModelType: 'virtual', 
            // other options ...
        }

  }

  onGridReady(
        this.api = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;

        this.api.setDatasource(this._createDatasource());
  }
```

In the datasource in the method `getRows(params)` I call `params.successCallback()`. The rows are then visible in the grid but no matter how I scroll the `getRows` is not invoked again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to continue scrolling the `lastRowIndex` in `params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRowIndex)` must resolve to `-1`.

Comment: Thanks! This just saved me a load of hassle as it came up as the top answer in a Google search.